# EIP-2981 royalty and opensea contractURI seller_fee_basis_points

Tags: opensea, eip-2981, royalty, contracturi

So both EIP-2981 `royaltyInfo()` and Opensea's `seller_fee_basis_points` from `contractURI()` represent royalties percentage awarded to creators. If I set both in a contract, which one will opensea take?

For example, I set 5% as `seller_fee_basis_points` and 3% for royaltyBPS returned from `royaltyInfo()` for all tokenIds.

When a token is sold, which one opensea would choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently OpenSea does not support EIP-2981 so you need to set the royalty on the contract level metadata in `seller_fee_basis_points`, however, I suggest you implement the Royalty Standard EIP-2981 in your contract; OpenSea is likely to implement the standard in the future with seaport. Implementing this standard will also future proof your contracts.

https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js/issues/482

Comment: Looks like Opensea is choosing not to add EIP-2981 support in Seaport. https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seaport/issues/306

Comment: Yeah... The only standard that carries information about creator royalties within the contract.. that was not a nice move